# Multiple sets of user setting windows form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a problem in my project.
My project is a class library. It include many Form(WindowsForm).
So. How to save many user setting for each form.
(I use Visual studio 2019 and at properties setting , it show me all property, not for each form)
I want to use code like  "My Form1.Properties.Settings.Default.MyProperty" or the same for each my form.
not like  "Properties.Settings.Default.Myproperty"
Thanks for your solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one Settings by default. If you want an easy way to tell which setting is used on which form, prefix the name, eg

```
loginForm.Width = Properties.Settings.Default.LoginForm_Width;
mainForm.Height = Properties.Settings.Default.MainForm_Height;
```

And so on

You complained "it is so long".. So either you can make an in class reference to it:

```
var s = Properties.Settings.Default;

loginForm.Width = s.LoginForm_Width;
mainForm.Height = s.MainForm_Height;
```

Or you databind it so that the controls get their own properties and settings (and store any changes to them back in the settings:

- make a settings file
- make settings
- drop eg a textbox
- in the property grid expand (ApplicationSettings)
- click the `[...]` next to (PropertyBinding)
- pick a property from the list that can be bound to the setting (i made a string setting so in my image I bind it to the Text property)
- OK

[image]

Now your settinngs and the control are connected - you change the Text in the textbox, the value of `Properties.Setting.Default.SettingX` changes. You save, quit, reload, the value is there again

Comment: Uhm... So be it . Although it is so long.

Comment: In case that was actually a real complaint, I made an edit

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much. I feel your slove  is useful. Thanks again.

Comment: No probs. To mark an answer as the one you used, click the grey tick to make it green. This lets other people know the query is resolved when they see it in the list.  To mark an answer as useful, click the up arrow. Any number of answers can be marked as useful but only one can be ticked.